# How to automatically put DIVs in columns (unknown number of DIVs)

Tags: javascript, php, css, html-table

I have a bit of code I wrote, that echo's 3 variable (quiz name, level and subject) inside a DIV, if there are 4 quizzes it will print 4 different DIVs.

However each div is printed on a different line, which doesn't make good use of space, as you could fit 3 on a line.

How would I go about getting it to print them in rows of 3?

I was thinking maybe a table? or javascript of somekind?

Here is my dose for the div, sorry it's not that clear. Also the CSS is on a different page, but is pretty basic, just defined it as a block.

```
for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++){?>
    <div class="quizBlock"><table>
    <tr align="left"><th colspan="2"><p class="subFontMe"><?php echo $quiz[$i]['Name']?></p></th></tr>
    <tr align="left"><th><p class="subFontSm"><?php echo $quiz[$i]['Level']?></p></th>
    <th><p class="subFontSm"><?php echo $sub[$quiz[$i]['Subject_ID']-1]['Subject']?></p></th></tr></p></table></div><br><?php }?>
```

Comment: I would think `float: left` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Demo of markup: http://jsfiddle.net/gut4S/

Comment: Also, please don't use tables for layout. See the fiddle I created above for a stray `</p>` in your markup, as well.

Comment: That doesn't work, because if I had, say ten divs, I would need it to be 3 rows of 3, and one row of 1. float left just puts them all to the left, which they already do??

Comment: Then give the `DIV`'s a `width: 33%` style property.

Comment: This sounds to me like an instance of tabular data.  In other words, the stuff you want to show is, in fact, a table, much like a bank statement is a table or a report card is a table.  I think a table is fine.

Comment: @Lissy: `float:left; width:33%;` after the last `<div>` do a `<br clear="all">`.

Comment: @Pointy - Then why each table in a `DIV`, with only `TH` elements? It may (or may not) be displayable as tabular data, but the layout approach itself is not tabular.

Comment: `float: left; width: 33%` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5Fb/

Comment: Well sure, what I meant was that it would make sense to put it in a `<table>` **properly** :-)

Comment: @Pointy - I think the OP wants to know how to accomplish her layout approach, though, which would be difficult to do with tables (as layout). My assumption is there is a reason to use blocks instead of rows, possibly a UI decision.

Comment: @JaredFarrish its not difficult to do with table more of a trade secrete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the divs to be aligned in a single line. then give float left property to it. and the width should be defined inside the class so that the parent div can accomodate three divs inside.

```
<?PHP

for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++){?>

<div class="quizBlock" style="float:left">
<table>
<tr align="left"><th colspan="2"><p class="subFontMe"><?php echo $quiz[$i]['Name']?></p></th></tr>
<tr align="left"><th><p class="subFontSm"><?php echo $quiz[$i]['Level']?></p></th>
<th><p class="subFontSm"><?php echo $sub[$quiz[$i]['Subject_ID']-1]['Subject']?></p></th></tr></p>    </table></div>

<?php } ?>
```

or you may want to try like:

```
<div class="quizBlock">
<table>
<?PHP

for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++){ ?>


<tr align="left">
<th colspan="2"><p class="subFontMe"><?php echo $quiz[$i]['Name']?></p></th>
<th><p class="subFontSm"><?php echo $quiz[$i]['Level']?></p></th>
<th><p class="subFontSm"><?php echo $sub[$quiz[$i]['Subject_ID']-1]['Subject']?></p></th>
</tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
</div>
```

which also put the data in separate rows.

Comment: The OP has stated that she would like it to be 3x3, for instance, so `float: left` only gets you halfway there.

Comment: @Jared Farrish : i removed the <br /> , added float:left and width should be adjusted to fit 3.. i think this will make it output 3*3 . Sorry if i miss read the question..

Comment: Where's the `width`? And wouldn't it good to at least mention putting the `float` and `width` properties in the `.quizBlock` class declaration?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I followed it, and it sort-of worked, although each div is a bit lowwer than the last, they go down like steps. Any idea what could be causing this, or how I could stop it? Thanks :)

Comment: @Lissy: some **margin** or **padding** property inside the **quizBlock** class should be causing it..

Comment: @mithunsatheesh - There could also be a border. You might ask for an http://jsfiddle.net demo of the **actual html output with CSS**, and point out Chrome and/or Firebug inspect element functionality. `:)` There could be a couple of different problems. (Note, I'll butt out and let you help her, I just wanted to mention border and console.)

Comment: @Jared Farrish : thanks for your help bro.. i just pointed out whatever came to my mind..

Comment: @Lissy: please put the css for the mentioned classes in the question. this may help in solving the question.

Comment: okay, actually it's just the first row of divs that do the weird steppy thing. I have tried removing all the padding, margins and boarders, and none of that worked :? Anyone got any more suggestions? and thanks again :)

Comment: try removingg the classes one by one and check if there s any change. also put the css also with the qn. using tools like firebug will alsoo help.

Comment: tried it :( I can't imagine what it could be, I've gone through and individually removed and replaced each part of my css and html, still no joy :/ but thanks for your help guys, wouldn't have even got this far with out all of you

Answer (score 1):

one way you use modulus checking if the remainder of `rows` divied by `3` equals 0.

I can give an example using javascript to dynamically populate divs to number of columns
it can be easly converted to php.

This example is not going to create the table via DOM.

```
var quiz = [['A',1,'Subject 1'],['B',3,'Subject 2'],['C',2,'Subject 3'],['D',78,'Subject 4']];

var t = document;
var m = quiz; // object data
var cols = 3 // num of cols

for(var j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {

 var c = t.createElement("div");
 c.className = "quizBlock"; // css class name

 var qbrs ='<table border=1 width=120><tr align="left"><th colspan="2"><p class="subFontMe">'+quiz[j][0]+'</p></th></tr><tr align="left"><th><p class="subFontSm">'+quiz[j][1]+'</p></th><th><p class="subFontSm">'+quiz[j][2]+'</p></th></tr></p></table>';

c.innerHTML = qbrs;

 // add clear float if 3rd value and not after last row also not before the first element
 if(j % cols == 0 && j != m.length && j != 0){ 
    var r = t.createElement("div");
    r.className = "clear";
    document.body.appendChild(r);
  }

 document.body.appendChild(c);

 }
```

let me know if this works for you